# Why is there always space remaining between action bar and view

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know: How can I remove the space between action bar and first text view nad it never fills whole screen in width too. A small space shows in on both sides?

```
tools:context="my.pro.imagination.islampro.mainpageactivity"
android:background="@drawable/rsz_background_green_by_dereque">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:src="@drawable/namaze"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="6 Kalimas"
    android:longClickable="true" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Islam Basics"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorHighlight="#ffff2720"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:background="#ff89ff24"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Comment: Dont give nay margin or padding.

Comment: show me your code what you have tried?

Comment: You've provided no detail and nothing to indicate what you've tried.

Comment: @Shahzaib Ch  Which textview you are talking about add some code ??

Comment: Removing padding of layout worked

Comment: Removing padding of layout worked

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by overriding actionbar style in style.xml

```
<style name="MyNoActionBarShadowTheme" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And update your activity theme in manifest.